# CSS Screen Orientation WebApp Rotation

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transforms

trying to lock my WebApp HTML to landscape Mode for HTML5 Video.
Have already found a great solution, but its rotate the screen into -90deg but i need +90deg... 
When i change the -90 to 90 the Video player disappears from screen.
I think the the `transform-origin` or and `top` or `left` is wrong.
Here the CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    html {
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform-origin: left top;
        width: 100vh;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post working copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `left:50px`...Because you've given `overflow-x:hidden` , you can't see it has been shifted to left because of plus rotation..

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait) {
   html {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    /*top: 100%;*/
    left: 50px;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Check it in mentioned screen width(320px to 767px)..

Comment: its working, can see part of the player in portrait modus, my css is showing full player, i think it has to be set to top0 or something

Comment: If you find it useful then don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for appreciation :)